# Angular 13 module federation IIS hosting give CORS error for MFs

Tags: angular, iis-7.5, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have a shell app [angular 13] hosted on my local IIS on port 2000 and a MF app which is hosted on IIS on port 1001.
I have loaded my MF within shell app using dynamic module federation in shell route.

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'pChild',
        loadChildren: () =>
          loadRemoteModule({
            type: 'module',
            remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:1001/remoteEntry.js',
            exposedModule: './AppModule',
          })
            .then((m) => {
              return m.AppModule;
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              return import('src/app/placeholder/error.module').then(
                (m) => m.ErrorModule
              );
            }),
      }]
```

I am getting CORS error for MF app.

> Access to script at 'http://localhost:1001/remoteEntry.js' from origin 'http://localhost:2000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**UPDATED**
*Proxy.conf.json*

```
{
"/localhost/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:2000/",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
}
```

}

and below are setting proxy in angular.json.

```
"serve": {
                    "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "shell:build:production",
                            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.prod.config.js",
                            "proxyConfig" : "src/proxy.conf.json"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "browserTarget": "shell:build:development"
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: Did you tried with adding proxy config for your angular app? you can refer the docs it will help and resolve the CORS issues. https://www.azilen.com/blog/how-to-resolve-cors-errors-by-using-angular-proxy

Comment: @KishanVaishnani Please see updated question. I have implemented prxy setting but still getting same error.

Comment: Does this problem only occur on iis? Does the angular app work fine locally?

Comment: @angfreak did you got any workaround for the above issue? i as well facing similar issue.

Comment: @cjdevin I found a solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution for this.

Go to IIS, click on your website, find the `HTTP RESPONSE HEADERS` icon, and configure it like this:

[image]

After that, there is a chance you still get an 404 error while trying to fetch a ".mjs" file, if that is the case, just add it to the mime types like this:

[image]

And that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
The issue in my case was that my remote app was a devServer (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) and under its `webpack.config.js` the cors configuration missed.

```
devServer: {
  ...,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }
},
```

Comment: i'm not using devServer, i'm using IIS, should this work as well for my case? I added it to the webpack.config.js in the host, but it does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this CORS error by enabling the CORS  in **web.config** in windows server.

Add the below configuration

```
<system.webServer>
         <httpProtocol>
             <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
             </customHeaders>
         </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

And also you need to enable the **mime file extension** of **.mjs**.
This can be also added in **web.config** file if you are using windows server.
Just to add the below code

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".mjs" mimeType="text/javascript" />      
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958591/nx-mfe-angular-module-federation-not-able-to-access-remote-micro-front-end)